# Query to get the partner each user has the most records with

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to get the partner company that each user has interacted the most with. There is a row for every interaction with the partner company. The WHERE clause is throwing an error.

```
SELECT user_id, partner_id, COUNT(partner_id)  
FROM users  
WHERE COUNT(partner_id) = MAX(COUNT(partner_id))  
GROUP BY user_id, partner_id;
```

Is there a way to have the count be the maximum count for the user? Without the WHERE the query runs, but then I get a list of all partners that interacted with each user, and the number of times the user interacted with each partner.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: can you post the error please

Comment: order by count and select only the top 1 row. Or use an outer query where you select the max of the inner result.

Answer (score 0):

This value is called the "mode" in statistics.  You can easily calculate it using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT user_id, partner_id, cnt
FROM (SELECT user_id, partner_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM users  
      GROUP BY user_id, partner_id
     ) u
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```